# My program runs fine from eclipse but gives array out of index exception in Terminal

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, terminal

I'm using eclipse for a Java project. This is how I get the input from the terminal:

```
java TicTacToe O X O X # O X O _ _ _ _ Y
```

These are arguments I put in eclipse:

O X O X # O X O _ _ _ _ Y

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char [][] board = new char [3][4];
    int strIncr = 0;
    char printFlag;

    //construct init board
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                board[i][j] = args[strIncr].charAt(0);
            strIncr++;
        }
    }
    printFlag = args[strIncr].charat(0);
}
```

**Problem:**

I seem to be getting an array out of index exception when running from terminal once i >=1. I do not encounter this issue while running from eclipse. I think the issue is related to the # because when I change that it works. help please.

Comment: In some UNIX shells hash denotes comments.

Comment: yes, just quote O X "#" X O

Comment: when in doubt, print it out. Printing your command line arguments would show you why it's breaking.

Comment: Thank you I believe this is the solution.